# Is there something like objective c nil terminate in php?

Tags: php, objective-c

In Objective-C, I can have a method like this:

```
+ (id)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...;
```

I can pass as many object as I like, until I pass a `nil` in the last argument.

In php, can I have this ability also...? Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you can do the same kind of thing -- except you don't have to pass null as a last parameter : just pass the parameters you want to your method.

Then, in this method, use functions such as [**`func_get_args()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to access the parameters it received.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "PHP Variable Arguments" on [Google](http://www.google.com) and found:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php
- http://www.bestcodingpractices.com/php_function_with_variable_arguments-9.html

Pro Tip: Google is free

Comment: Thank you, I don't know this is called "Variable Arguments".... Now I know. Thanks.